# Could not find matching constructor for Wait Condition in Jmeter using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy, jmeter, webdriverwait, jmeter-plugins

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

//var wait = new WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000)
//var wait = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser,    Java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(60))
    WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
    WDS.browser.get(url)
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id('idSIButton9')));
    var nextbtn=WDS.browser.findElement(By.id('idSIButton9'));
    nextbtn.click();

    WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

I was expecting it will run without giving errors. But it gave me below error
Giving error for for long and integer variables. Which constructor will match with the new version?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLITT.png)

```
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver, Long)
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158)
at java.scripting/javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:262)
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:101)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```

This is the sample code i have written in Jmeter. It is giving error for the commented variables of wait condition. I tried both the methods. Its giving error for both the ways of wait conditions. There is compatibility issue maybe. As its new version of jmeter. Only wait condition is giving error.
I am using all updated version. Jmeter version is 5.5. And all the other plugins are also updated.
Will be helpful if provided any inputs on the wait condition.
Its in Groovy language
Tried all the methods. Mothing is working for wait condition.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "lib" folder of your JMeter installation and look for `selenium-*` libraries. It should contain the version. Then check [Selenium JavaDoc](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/overview-summary.html) for particular that version.

If you got your Selenium libraries via [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin current version [4.9.1.0](https://jmeter-plugins.org/files/packages/jpgc-webdriver-4.9.1.0.zip) is based on Selenium 4.9.1.0 and the API contract states that second argument should be not Long but [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html)

So the equivalent "new" code would be something like:

```
var wait = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, java.time.Duration.ofMillis(5000))
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)